# Java Spring boot multiple security adapters

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have the following security adapters:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

     @Configuration
        @Order(1)                                                        
        public static class ApiWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

            @Autowired CommonApplicationProperties commonProperties;
            @Autowired DashboardApplicationProperties applicationProperties;

            @Autowired
            private CustomAuthenticationProvider authProvider;

            @Override
            protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
                auth.authenticationProvider(authProvider);
            }

            @Override
            public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
                 web.ignoring().antMatchers(
                         "/app/**",
                         "/assets/**",
                         "/webjars/**"
                         );
            }



        @Override 
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

            http.csrf().disable()
            .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .httpBasic().disable()
            .formLogin().disable()
            .logout()
            .logoutSuccessHandler((new CustomLogoutSuccessHandler(applicationProperties)))
            .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
            .and()
            .addFilter(new TokenBasedAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager(), applicationProperties, commonProperties.getAuthTokenSecret()))
            .addFilter(new TokenBasedAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager(), applicationProperties, commonProperties.getAuthTokenSecret()));

            http.headers()
            .contentSecurityPolicy("default-src 'none'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; connect-src 'self'; img-src 'self' data:; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; font-src 'self' data:;");

            http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/*").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated();

     }

     @Order(2)        
     @Configuration
        public static class DashboardSecurityAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

         @Autowired DashboardApplicationProperties applicationProperties;
         @Autowired CommonApplicationProperties commonProperties;

            @Override
            protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

                System.out.println("Dashboard Login Enable");

                http.csrf().disable()
                .requestMatchers()
                .antMatchers("/assets/**", "/*")
                .and()
                .httpBasic().disable()
                .formLogin().disable();

                http.headers()
                .contentSecurityPolicy("default-src 'none'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; connect-src 'self'; img-src 'self' data:; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; font-src 'self' data:;");
            }
        }
```

The first one is working.
The second one should do the same trick, just without the two `addFilter` methods.
Unfortunetly, I can't find the content security policy header on the `DashboardSecurityAdapter`.

Any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure you can have multiple security configurations like this. What you can do is chain multiple HTTP configurations in a single security configuration. It looks like what you are trying to do is secure your application, while allowing anyone to access static asset files. I would do something like this:

```
    @Override 
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.csrf().disable()
            .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
         .and()
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/assets/**").permitAll()
         .and()
            .httpBasic().disable()
            .formLogin().disable()
            .logout()
            .logoutSuccessHandler((new CustomLogoutSuccessHandler(applicationProperties)))
            .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
         .and()
            .addFilter(new TokenBasedAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager(), applicationProperties, commonProperties.getAuthTokenSecret()))
            .addFilter(new TokenBasedAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager(), applicationProperties, commonProperties.getAuthTokenSecret()));

 }
```

Comment: Thanks, but will the `http.headers()
            .contentSecurityPolicy("default-src 'none'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; connect-src 'self'; img-src 'self' data:; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; font-src 'self' data:;");` apply to the static files as well? I need it there. only the `AddFilter` should not be included.

Comment: @TheUnreal I believe it will since it is not tied to a specific matcher, but you will need to test that to confirm.